# R : check whether two rows are connected using a reference matrix

Tags: r, matrix, machine-learning, svd

I have IDs which are [A,B,C,D] and a reference matrix which is below and it tells that which IDs are connected.If they have 1 or -1 in the cell, then we could say they are connected, So from this matrix we could say 'A' is connected with 'B' and 'C' likewise all connected IDs are represented in the matrix below
`#   A  B  C  D 
 A   0  1 -1  0 
 B   1  0  0  1 
 C  -1  0  0  0 
 D   0  1  0  0`

Now I have second matrix which have rows with IDs as a subset of the all IDs. Columns of this matrix are not IDs.
`#    X1   X2   X3 
 A   1.5  1.6  0.7 
 D   0.9  1.3  1.4 
 C   0.7  1.1  1.8`

now I want to find  which rows in the second matrix are connected using the first reference matrix.I expect to create another matrix that have rows of the second matrix but should tell whether they are connected or not referring the first matrix. I expect a matrix as below as my result.
`#   A   D   C 
 A   0   0   1 
 D   0   0   0 
 C   1   0   0`
please suggest me how can i achieve this in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used match on the rownames. Let me know if this works for you/ if you have any questions.

```
matrix1 <- matrix(c(0, 1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), ncol = 4, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:4], LETTERS[1:4]))
matrix1
   A B  C D
A  0 1 -1 0
B  1 0  0 1
C -1 0  0 0
D  0 1  0 0

matrix2 <- matrix(c(1.5, 1.6, 0.7, 0.9, 1.3, 1.4, 0.7, 1.1, 1.8), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(c("A","D","C"), paste0("X",1:3)))
matrix2
   X1  X2  X3
A 1.5 1.6 0.7
D 0.9 1.3 1.4
C 0.7 1.1 1.8

matched_rows <- match(rownames(matrix2), rownames(matrix1))
matched_cols <- match(rownames(matrix2), colnames(matrix1))
matrix3 <- abs(matrix1[matched_rows, matched_cols])
matrix3
  A D C
A 0 0 1
D 0 0 0
C 1 0 0
```

Comment: Its perfect working as expected. Thank you very much.